# How to provide classpath to Executable JAR file in mac terminal

Tags: java

I have an executable jar file i.e. main class is bundled in the jar with manifest entry.
I was able to run the jar file with the following command:

```
java -jar myApp.jar
```

Which is able to pick my main class.
Because of some libraries missing in the executable jar file, I am getting ClassNotFoundException.

So, to fix the class not found errors, I tried to pass few more jar files as classpath to the java command as below:

```
java -classpath /Users/lib/httpclient.jar:/Users/lib/commons-logging.jar -jar myApp.jar
```

But my main class is not able to find the jar files specified in **-classpath** argument.

Added print statement in my main class as below:

```
System.out.println("Classpath: " + System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
```

This print statement is printing the classpath as below

```
Classpath: myApp.jar
```

Why I am not able to see the other jars(httpclient.jar & commons-logging.jar) in classpath? How to add those jar files to classpath for executable jar file in mac terminal?

Comment: are you sure you use the right path? `/Users/lib/httpclient.jar` looks strange, as if there is a user named "lib" which is very unlikely.

Comment: From `man java`: `When you use the -jar option, the specified JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other class path settings are ignored.`

Comment: @cello I have jar files available in that path.

Comment: put your `myApp.jar` also as part of the -classpath